# Can you make a table in a MySQL database that is an alias for the same table in another database?

Tags: mysql

I have a database called `London`, which has a `users` table in it.

I also have a database called `New York`, which has a `users` table in it.

They're on the same server, but they're different databases.

I want these databases to continue being entirely separate - but I'd like to share just the user table between both. Specifically, I'd really like the `New York` database to use the `users` table from the `London` database.

Can I tell my mySQL server (it's actually Amazon RDS Aurora) to symbolically link my `users` table in `New York` to the real one in `London`? Or can I sync the two somehow so that new data in one gets automatically copied to another?

I don't really know what I'm searching for or what this is called, hence my stupid question. Sorry.

Comment: Is it an option to use a view?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. What you can do is:

```
use NewYork;
CREATE VIEW users AS SELECT * FROM London.users;
```